# Is there a way to get the complete console output on xcode through code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I need to read the entire console output so i'd like to implement a functionality which will send everything that was printed out to my email or something like that.

Is it possible?

I do realize that I could just use a different function for logging print statements etc but i need the outputs from the 3rd party libs as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the log to a file and then email it. I put the snippet here. Just one question, why would you want to retrieve the log by mail?

Objective-c

```
 NSArray *allPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [allPaths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *pathForLog = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"logfile.log"];

 freopen([pathForLog cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],"a+",stderr);
```

**Swift**

```
let allPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
let documentsDirectory = allPaths.first!
let pathForLog = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingString("/logfile.log")

freopen(pathForLog.cStringUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!, "a+", stderr)
```

Comment: I used the email to exemplify, i'm actually thinking about attaching it to the crash reporter. But thanks! I'll let you know if it works real soon.